# How can i know all about NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I am new in iPhone.i want to know all about NSString so please give me some idea about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most appropriate place to start with is Apple Documentation.

- [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i)
- [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

Answer (score 4):

**It seems that one can't do much better than the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).**

If you have a more *specific* question about `NSString`, please edit your question to include it.